# Pandas: Filtering only headers, first cell value, and cell value: if a cell(s) in row meets condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple excel files in the following format (each w/ different stuff being tracked, ie different 'activity' headers):

```
| Name | Activity1 | Activity2 | Activity3 | Activity4 | 

 Timmy   2016-04-01  2016-12-30  2016-01-14  2016-03-04  
 John    2016-01-01  2016-12-12  2016-05-14  2016-11-02  
 Paul    2016-05-11  2016-04-17  2016-04-19  2015-07-02
```

... etc

I am trying to iterate over all the files in a specified folder - convert to a Pandas dataframes - then process the files to generate a report - show the 'Name' and return the value of any cell which has a date BEFORE the current date, maintain the header if there is an 'offending' cell as well (for readablilty).  A sample output would look something like:

```
| Name | Activity1 | Activity3 | Activity4 | 

 Timmy  empty cell?  2016-01-14  2016-03-04

 John    2016-01-01  2016-04-19  2015-07-02
```

Paul and df['Activity2'] being absent since they had no cell values prior to current date.

I have been having issues returning specific cells to get the output Im looking for, however, I think I have been able to filter entire rows if a cell in the row meets the above condition.  Ill paste my code below;  Please feel free to pass any other general advise along if you see some blatently terrible practices.  I am self taught so I can only assume I don't do things the best way possible.

... leaving out the function passing/setup stuff and going straight to the filtering portion:

```
current_date = '{0:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())

output = dataframe[
    (dataframe['Flu Shot'] < current_date) | (dataframe['PHA'] < current_date) | (dataframe['Dental'] < current_date) | (dataframe['HIV'] < current_date)
]
```

This will return the ENTIRE row if a cell has the specified condition, however, I still get the cell values that I am not concerned with.  I am not crazy about the very lengthy conditional check - but it was the only thing I could get to work.

I had also tried something like the code below - but was unable to get it to work right, and was told it was an absolutely awful way to utilize pandas dataframes:

```
headers = list(dataframe.columns.values)

for header in headers[1:4]:    # index 0 being 'Name'
    frame = "'{}'".format(header)
    if frame == 'Name':
        continue
    elif dataframe[frame] < current_date:
        output.concat(dataframe.iloc[['Name', frame]])
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the filtering, you can do the comparision all at once, you don't have to specify each of the columns separately:

```
In [20]: df[df > current_date]
Out[20]:
    Name   Activity1   Activity2   Activity3   Activity4
0  Timmy  2016-04-01  2016-12-30         NaN         NaN
1   John         NaN  2016-12-12  2016-05-14  2016-11-02
2   Paul  2016-05-11  2016-04-17  2016-04-19         NaN
```

Comment: I am still getting the error below, do you know why it would throw this when I use the df[df < current_date] but not when I used the very long version I had written?


    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-03-10'

Comment: it could be that you have an integer column in there that it's trying to do the comparison with, if this is the case, you'll need to filter for the "activity" columns only, for example with `df.filter(like = 'Activity')`